# Extensions of $\mathfrak{p}$-adic Valuation

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm studying Neukirch's ANT and I came across something that I don't understand on page 165. It says:

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be a Dedekind domain with field of fractions $K$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Then we can define the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic valuation $v_\mathfrak{p}$ on $K$ by
$$v_\mathfrak{p}(a) = \nu_\mathfrak{p}, \ (a) = \prod \mathfrak{p}^{\nu_\mathfrak{p}}$$ for $a \in K$.
Let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension and let $\mathcal{O}_L$ be the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_K$ inside $L$. Then $\mathcal{O}_L$ is again a Dedekind domain and we obtain the factorization
$$\mathfrak{p} \mathcal{O}_L = {\mathfrak{P}_1}^{e_1} ... {\mathfrak{P}_r}^{e_r}$$
into primes of $\mathcal{O}_L$. $\textbf{The extensions of $v_\mathfrak{p}$ to $L$ are exactly the $\frac{1}{e_i} v_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$.}$

The highlighted part is the part I don't understand. I see how they give extensions of $v_\mathfrak{p}$ but how do I know that all of the extensions are of the form $\frac{1}{e_i} v_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$? Could someone give me a hint?

Trying to follow the idea in the answer of @hunter:

Let $\nu$ be an extension of $v$ to $L$. The valuation $\nu$ has image $s \mathbb{Z} \cup \infty$ for some $s \in \mathbb{Q}$ and its set of elements with positive valuation is $\mathfrak{P}$, which has to correspond to one of the $\mathfrak{P}_i$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$. We claim that $\nu = s v_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$. To see this it suffices to show that the two valuations agree on $\mathcal{O}_L-\{0\}$ because for $x \in L^*$ either $x \in \mathcal{O}_L-\{0\}$ or $x^{-1} \in \mathcal{O}_L-\{0\}$. So let $x \in \mathcal{O}_L-\{0\}$ then $\nu(x) \geq 0$.
If $\nu(x) = 0$ then $x \notin \mathfrak{P}_i$ so $v_{\mathfrak{P}_i}(x) = 0$. Let $\pi$ be a prime element of $\nu$ in $\mathfrak{P}_i$.
If $\nu(x) = sn$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $x = \pi^n u$ with $u \in \mathcal{O}_L^*$. So $(x) = (\mathfrak{P}_i)^n$ which shows that $s \nu_{\mathfrak{P}_i}(x) = sn$. Since $\nu$ is an extension of $v$ we have $s = 1/e_i$.

I guess one final thing to add would be that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is the valuation ring of $\nu$. I think this follows because for $x \in L$ we have $\nu(x) \geq 0$ iff $x$ is integral over $\mathcal{O}_K$. It doesn't seem like we used the separability assumption so maybe that's not necessary...

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a valuation $\nu: L \to \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\}$ extending $v_\mathfrak{p}$. (Putting rationals for the value group to avoid thinkinag about normalization.)

Write $\mathfrak{P}$ for the set of elements (EDIT: of $\mathcal{O}_L$) positive valuation. Then you can check manually that $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime ideal. It must contain $\mathfrak{p}$ since all these elements have positive valuation, so $\mathfrak{P}$ is one of your $\mathfrak{P_i}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think I understood. I added some stuff to my question to understand your answer better, if you have time it would be nice if you could have a look!

Comment: @M. Wang Since these rings aren't PIDs, the prime element $\pi$ might not exist. Also I'm not sure what it means to check that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is the valuation ring of $\nu$ (it's not true that it's the set of stuff with non-negative valuaton; there will be lots of stuff in $L \setminus \mathcal{O}_L$ with positive valuation.)

Comment: I see. So how would your answer imply that $\nu$ is one of the $\frac{1}{e_i} v_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$?

Comment: @M.Wang Localize the whole picture at $\mathbb{P}$, and then everything is a PID.

Comment: But I think I still wouldn't be able to apply my reasoning since $\mathcal{O}_L$ is not the valuation ring of $\nu$. So how would it follow that $\mathfrak{P}$ is contained in $\mathcal{O}_L$?

Comment: @M. Wang You have the valuation $\nu$ on the Dedekind domain $\mathcal{O}_L$ such that the ideal of positive elements is exactly $\mathfrak{P}$. In addition, there is the valuation $v_\mathfrak{P}$, which has this property. Your concern is that they might be different (not just up to normalization?)

Comment: Yes, this is my concern. Also, I think $\nu$ is a valuation on $L$ and not on $\mathcal{O}_L$ as you also wrote in your answer. You also said that in general there could be lots of stuff in $L - \mathcal{O}_L$ that has positive valuation so we wouldn't necessarily have $\mathfrak{P} \subset \mathcal{O}_L$.

Comment: @M. Wang re: your second question -- my answer was not written well, sorry -- see the edit. We are *defining* $\mathfrak{P}$ to be the subset of the integers with positive valuation. So the only remaining question is if there can be two different valuations with the same ideal of positive elements. You can handle this by localizing, in which case you may assume there is a uniformizer.